# Grub entry not booting up

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, grub

My grub installation broke recently. I attempted to fix it by running the following commands from my Ubuntu distribution and Arch Linux distribution:

```bsh
sudo os-prober
sudo grub-mkconfig /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/EFI /dev/nvme0n1
```

Now grub shows all my installed operating systems again and I can use it to boot into two of my installed OS. However, one menu item still does not allow me to boot the corresponding Linux distribution. When I select it, the Laptop's start screen (a large lenovo icon) appears and nothing happens afterwards. Have you got any hints how I can fix this or gather further information on why it does not boot?

The grub menu- entry that does not load up from the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
menuentry 'Arch Linux (rolling) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc' {
        savedefault
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0DD8-ECF1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0DD8-ECF1
        fi
        linux /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc rw loglevel=3 quiet
        initrd /intel-ucode.img
}
```

and I double-checked with blkid that the UUID `53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc` corresponds to the correct drive (`/dev/nvme0n1p5`) and the UUID from the `search` command corresponds to `/dev/nvme0n1p1` which is the EFI Boot.

**edit**: I followed @Recct 's suggestion and removed the "quiet", and also increased the loglevel to 7. Then I receive the errors from the image below, I think the most relevant section is the following:

```
No filesystem could mount root, tried:

Kernell panic - not syncing VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0, 0)
```

[image: Image of the error]

### edit 2:

Now I have succeeded in adding my other distro to the grub.cfg file a second time, this time it boots up (I don't really understand what I did though), adding /initramfs-linux.img to the initrd command was the essential change.

As I understand it the file should be automatically generated by grub-mkconfig based on /etc/grub.d and /etc/default/grub though.
How do I change the settings in /etc/grub.d to fix this permanently?

```
menuentry 'Arch Linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc' {
    savedefault
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0DD8-ECF1
    echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc rw  loglevel=7 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /intel-ucode.img /initramfs-linux.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Arch Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc' {
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-advanced-c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc' {
    savedefault
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0DD8-ECF1
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc rw  loglevel=3 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /intel-ucode.img /initramfs-linux.img
    }
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux (fallback initramfs)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-fallback-c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc' {
    savedefault
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0DD8-ECF1
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc rw  loglevel=3 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /intel-ucode.img /initramfs-linux-fallback.img
    }
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux (recovery mode)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-recovery-c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0DD8-ECF1
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=c53daa31-996c-468d-bd57-df5b73cb87cc rw single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /intel-ucode.img /initramfs-linux-fallback.img
    }
}
```

Comment: If you remove that `quiet` and try, you should/might get a verbose output instead of the logo (or after it) that will hang at a certain stage, that might give us some hints

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/628206/how-can-i-boot-into-arch-linux-using-initramfs-in-ubuntus-grub